# Repository + Unit of Work + Service Layer + Controllers/Consumers (Asp.Net, Background Service, Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture

Recently I have read many articles on how to use the Unit of Work and Repository pattern, also different opinions on not to use it because it is just an additional layer of complexity and how Entity Framework DbContext is allready such an implementation.
Also many of the tutorials are simple ones where the code is kind of the following code:

```
public Task<IAsyncResult> ControllerTestMethod(...)
{
   await _testUnitOfWork.TestRepository.AddAsync(...);
   await _testUnitOfWork.CommitAsync();
}
```

This is kind of the simple variant where the UoW instantiates the TestRepository.

In the solution that we are currently **refactoring** we have the following layering:

```
// layer 1 Controllers
public TestController(ITestService testService)
// layer 2 Services
public TestService(ITestRepository testRepository, ITestItemsRepository testItemsRepository)
// layer 3 Repositories
public TestRepository(TestDbContext context)
public TestItemsRepository(TestDbContext context)
```

A simple flow in the service would be represented by something like

```
public async Task TestIt()
{
   var test = _testRepository.GetAsync(...)
   // business logic
   await _testRepository.UpdateAsync(...)
   await _testItemsRepository.UpdateAsync(...)
}
```

- Of course this is not DDD, there is a lack of clearly defined Aggregate root and many other things, but life is not easy, you try to be a boy-scout and make things better without being an expert and learning things on the way...
- As you have noticed the main concern is no atomicity, lack of transactions, performance degradation because of multiple roundtrips to the DB.
- The repository calls SaveChangesAsync in each operation hitting the DB each time.
- If some repository call fails in the middle, the data might get inconsistent.

At this step of refactoring eventual consistency seems to be out of the question so we are trying to go into the direction of UnitOfWork or Transactions.
Thinking on where would the UnitOfWork fit in regarding layers.

Questions and discussion points where any help would be appreciated

**I.** Thinking on the fact that Unit of Work calling SaveChangesAsync at the end with the Repositories not hitting the DB would be better then explicit transactions because of the following:

**a.** Single roundtrip (if not too many operations in batch) to the database vs multiple roundtrips with explicit transaction having multiple SaveChangesAsync

**b.** Taking advantage of EF features (including here also retry execution strategy ...)
.....

**II.** UnitOfWork unit testing and dependency injection through Service layer

Do not really like the version where the UnitOfWork creates the instance of the repository and exposes it through getters
Even if for me it seems good to have the UnitOfWork control the Repository because the same DBContext should be used in both UnitOfWork and repositories I have an issue on doing everything through _testUnitOfWork.TestRepository.DoSomething(...) because from the service point of view does not feel right to have the entire UnitOfWork injected as dependency into the services and refactoring it to something like

```
epublic TestService(IUnitOfWork testUnitOfWork)
...
public async Task TestIt()
{
   var test = _testRepository.GetAsync(...)
   // business logic
   await _testUnitOfWork.TestRepository.UpdateAsync(...)
   await _testUnitOfWork.TestItemsRepository.UpdateAsync(...)
   await _testUnitOfWork.CommitAsync()
}
```

What I also feel is not the cleanest way but currently the best solution perhaps is just to have the UnitOfWork having the DbContext injected and no knowledge about the Repositories. This way the code would look like

```
public TestService(ITestRepository testRepository, ITestItemsRepository testItemsRepository)
....
public async Task TestIt()
{
   var test = _testRepository.GetAsync(...)
   // business logic
   await _testRepository.UpdateAsync(...)
   await _testItemsRepository.UpdateAsync(...)
   await _testUnitOfWork.CommitAsync()
}
```

This seems to be doable through the dependency injection mechanism by having scoped lifetime registrations so that the same DbContext is injected into both UnitOfWork and repositories but I have some concerns

**a.** Any service will have a UnitOfWork passed in that has several getters returning several Repositories even if the service would use only a couple of them. Other option I see is to have all kind of unit of works in combination with different repositories depending on the need of the service (you might say aggregate roots and UnitOfWork on the aggregate root, but still as the current implementation there are valid scenarios where only some of the repositories are involved in the operation, and other scenarios where more repositories are involved)

**b.** Unit testing is not so straight forward but might be acceptable by setting up the getters of the IUnitOfWorkMock to return an ITestRepositoryMock ....
(It is not recommended from what I understand to have DbContext directly injected without repositories and test through and InMemoryDatabase)

**c.** What about the scenario where the consumer is a background task or windows services or somtehing where the scope and the lifetime of the DbContext is not so straight forward. The functionality would be to have an infinite loop where data is retrieved and updated.
In this case is it even acceptable to have a single instance of the UnitOfWork and DbContext and call several times CommitAsync through the same instance of TestService like:

```
while (true)
{
   // do stuff
  await _testService.TestIt();
}
```

Would it be valid or better to explicitly create a scope at each run to have different UnitOfWork and DBContext instances like:

```
while (true)
{
   using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
   {
      var testService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ItestService>();
      // do stuff
      await testService.TestIt();
   }
}
```

**III.** Where should the UnitOfWork be injected at the end since we have reusable services being part of bigger flows (somekind of enlisting multiple services in unit of work) like the following:

```
public class SuperComplexTestService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
   public SuperComplexTestService()
   ....
   public async Task TestAll(..)
   {
      await _testService.TestIt(..);
      foreach (.....)
      {
         await someOtherService.DoIt(...);
      }
      await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync()
   }
}
```

In conclusion would be happy to hear about any suggestions on how to refactor the current solution with hundreds of services having specific repositories injected, into a solution with transactional support using Entity Framework (preferably UnitOfWork because of less Database calls and other mentioned features...)

Also maybe you have some hints on how this should be implemented from the scratch(for future whishful thinking where time is unlimited and we can rewrite what we want)

Maybe some reference application with service layer and unit of work (Not thinking at this point on eventual consistency over distributed transaction scenarios with multiple data sources)

Take into account the points mentioned and current architecture and the fact that we cannot rewrite everything from scratch.

Comment: The UoW pattern I use and recommend is Medhi's DbContextScope (https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope) There are forks for EF Core. It creates a clear separation of responsibility for what the UoW does (DbContextScope) in terms of setting the scope and overseeing the "Commit" via it's `SaveChanges` wrapper, while the Repositories can locate the ContextScope they are called within to get a DbContext reference. Repositories can call SaveChanges if they absolutely need to (such as to fetch an identity value) but it is the DbContextScope that ultimately commits the Tx.

Comment: @StevePy this is very interesting and I will look into, congrats also to the author, but no releases yet, don't no if it is production ready code (I don't think CallContext is supported in .net core in order to have the ambient context available also in task continuations on different threads).
Do you think it is a better alternative then creating specific scopes with services.CreateScope() in non web applications in order to controle the scope?

Comment: For .Net Core implementations there have been Forks to bring it forward. In the ever-changing landscape of .Net Core.  There have been a few more forks since I last looked, I do wish GitHub had some better views to organize Forks to see who has been working on things more recently. I do see one for .Net 5: https://github.com/yegor-mialyk/DbContextScope  At a minimum it can serve as a reference for ideas on how to manage responsibility between the UoW (Scope) and the repositories.  Personally I use it primarily for web applications.